# How to convert a simple VLOOKUP to XLOOKUP in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, database, vlookup, lookup

The VLOOKUP works as intended.  The XLOOKUP is giving "#NAME" error:

[image: xlookup failure]

screenshot of the formula:

[image: excel]

the working VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(C12,B24:C29,2,FALSE)
```

Which I'm reading as "take the value from c12", look at the table B24:C29, lookup the second column.

the not functional XLOOKUP:

```
=XLOOKUP(C11,B24:B29,C24:C29)
```

which I'm reading as:

lookup the value in C11, Find the value in the range B24:B29, return the corresponding value in C24:C29.

Possibly I've made a typo, but maybe I'm not understanding the XLOOKUP function sufficiently.

Primarily I'm using Microsoft Co-Pilot and then also reading tutorials.

I'll use the Markdown editor, but a copy paste of data:

```
Client Name SKU Item Name
McGowan 294211  =XLOOKUP(C11,B24:B29,C24:C29)
Grossman    327064  =VLOOKUP(C12,B24:C29,2,FALSE)
Chamberlain 446741   
Vong    643081   
Williams    294211   
Hicks   446741   
Singh   306862   
Zach    643081   
Li  446741   
Totals       
         
         
SKU Description Price
294211  Leather sectional   1399
306862  Entertainment center    809.99
327064  Media cabinet   379.99
446229  Suede recliner  1099.99
446741  End table set   467.99
643081  Dining table    599.99
```

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the Markdown Table Generator, thanks and I'll look into it.

Comment: oh, okay, well, it's just the version.  But thanks for the info about the table generator.  Generally, how would I determine whether a function was supported or not?

Comment: A simple way to determine is by typing the said function, if when entering `=XLOOKUP(` in cell shows up then its supported else not, unless you have some addins. Also, if you goto `Formulas` Tab Ribbon and click on `Lookup & Reference` you will get to see the function. Highly suggested to read `MSFT` documentations.

Comment: Also please read for what reasons `#NAME?` error can appear --> [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-name-error-b6d54e31-a743-4d7d-9b61-40002a7b4286)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First things first:*

Your `VLOOKUP()` function shown in OP will certainly return wrong output from `14` th row onwards. The second parameter of `VLOOKUP()` function is **`table_array`** which needs to be either relative absolute reference like `B$24:C$29` if not filled right or total absolute reference `$B$24:$C$29`. That said the formula will be:

[image]

---

```
=VLOOKUP(C11,B$24:C$29,2,0)
```

---

*Secondly,*

`XLOOKUP()` function is available from `Excel 2021+` onwards however, I am not sure why [Excel_Functions_List_From_MSFT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188#bm24) still shows only for `MS365`, not updated may be. **Great resource** to learn even if you don't have the said function, if you have then else create an `Hotmail/Outlook` account and use `Excel On Web` to learn the usages of the said function. [XLOOKUP_with_examples](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929).

---

*Thirdly,*

Even though its unnecessary, to use an alternative method to `VLOOKUP()` function, but you can try to use just for learning `INDEX()`+`MATCH()` function or `VLOOKUP()`+`CHOOSE()` or `VLOOKUP()`+`IF()`. Note that the last two combination of formulas are not as efficient like `VLOOKUP()` and `INDEX()`+`MATCH()` functions. That said.

• Using `INDEX()`+`MATCH()`

```
=INDEX(C$24:C$29,MATCH(C11&"",B$24:B$29&"",0))
```

---

• Using `VLOOKUP()`+`IF()` or with `CHOOSE()`

[image]

---

```
=VLOOKUP(C11,IF({1,0},B$24:B$29,C$24:C$29),2,FALSE)
```

---

Or,

```
=VLOOKUP(C11,CHOOSE({1,2},B$24:B$29,C$24:C$29),2,FALSE)
```

---

**Note:** Both `VLOOKUP()` combo functions would need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode based on ones `Excel Versions`.

---

An OLD SCHOOL approach, using `LOOKUP()` function:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(B$24:B$29&""=C11&""),C$24:C$29)
```

---

[image]

---

Just note the above formula works when using the lookup vector is in ascending order, otherwise you may get `FALSE POSITIVES`. Therefore, the conclusion is its better to use `XLOOKUP()` (if one have the version of excel) else use `VLOOKUP()` or `INDEX()`+`MATCH()` (as and when required).

---